# How to slow down the animation?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have animation rectangle [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kHvaX/)

How to slow down the animation and make it more stable?

I try to use loop delay but there is conflict between the delay loop and requestAnimationFrame

I dont want to change the parameters `window.setTimeout(f, 1e3 / 60);`

becose there is more block of code which require good preferences.

Many thanks.

***loop delay :***

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {}, i * 2000);
        }(i));
    }
```

***My code :***

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var my_gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);

    window.requestAnimationFrame = function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(f) {
        window.setTimeout(f,1e3/60);
      }
  }();


  window.cancelAnimationFrame = function() {
    return window.cancelAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozCancelAnimationFrame ||
      window.msCancelAnimationFrame ||
      window.oCancelAnimationFrame ||
      function(f) {
        window.setTimeout(f,1e3/60);
      }
  }();  
var randompos = {};
RandomPosition();

function DrawBackround() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    my_gradient.addColorStop(0, '#002EB8');
    my_gradient.addColorStop(1, '#4D6DCD');
    ctx.fillStyle = my_gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
}

function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

function RandomPosition() {
    DrawBackround();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    var dt = 10;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                randompos.x = 0;
                randompos.y = dt; //12
                break;
            case 2:
                randompos.x = dt;
                randompos.y = dt; //1
                break;
            case 3:
                randompos.x = dt;
                randompos.y = 0; //3
                break;
            case 4:
                randompos.x = dt;
                randompos.y = -dt; //4
                break;
            case 5:
                randompos.x = 0;
                randompos.y = -dt; //6
                break;
            case 6:
                randompos.x = -dt;
                randompos.y = -dt;
                break;
            case 7:
                randompos.x = -dt;
                randompos.y = 0;
                break;
            case 8:
                randompos.x = -dt;
                randompos.y = dt;
                break;
            default:
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = get_random_color();
        ctx.fillRect(randompos.x + 50, randompos.y + 50, 100, 100);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(RandomPosition);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {}, i * 2000);
        }(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a setTimeout of `1e3/60` and not just `8`?

Comment: Same type of Question is there in this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875307/slow-down-for-loop-to-animate-canvas

Comment: becose there is more block of code which require good preferences.

Comment: I will tell you the diffrent between my code and [stackoverflow.com/questions/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875307/slow-down-for-loop-to-animate-canvas) I use with requestAnimationFrame becose I have more havy code for animation instead short code whice no reqire good optimal preferences

Comment: Please check [This](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to slow down your particular function would be to make it run only every X frames,

Editing your RandomPosition() to something like this makes it run once every 10 frames:

```
var counter=0;
function RandomPosition() {
    if(++counter % 10){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(RandomPosition);
        return false;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaibuu/kHvaX/1/

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
setInterval(code, milliseconds);
```

It returns a number that you need to save so you can stop the code. So we can write:

```
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
     clock();
     x++;
     if (x > 90) clearInterval(interval);
 }, 30);
```

This creates a function that occurs every 30 milliseconds.

Every 30 milliseconds, clock() is called, x is incremented, and if x is more than 90 we call clearInterval and pass in the number that our call to setInterval returned. This makes sure that the code open happens 90 times total.

Comment: I dont know How to do it becose setInterval is loop and allso requestAnimationFrame  is aloop . I must to put 1 loop in other loop then there is the problem the conflict is loop inside loop inside loop etc......